# Hibernate Query for group by month/year from LocalDate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity class

```
@Entity

public class Status{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="STATUS_SEQ")
    Long id;

    String  statusValue;

    @Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
    LocalDate date;


    //some other attributes
    //getter and setters

}
```

`statusValue` can contain different statuses like OPEN, CLOSE, NEW, HOLD, INPROGRESS

**Note:** I have implemented the custom physical naming strategy also which is Prefixed t_ for all tables and prefix c_ for all columns, so column name in the database and in entity are not sam

**Issue:** I am trying find the date wise count for a month for different statuses. I wrote the below query in SQL.

```
SELECT c_status_value,
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM c_date),
  COUNT(this_.c_status_value)
FROM t_status
WHERE 
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c_date) = 12
GROUP BY c_status_value,EXTRACT(DAY FROM c_date);
```

Now in the code, I don't want to write a native query which but want to write something in hibernate. I have tried using the `Criteria`, but in that to `extract` when I am using date field its not applying the naming strategy and eventually `EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)` which is not working because there is no field in database as `date` .

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("EXTRACT(MONTH from {alias}.date) = (:?)", month,tipos));
```

I am open for any solution also which can give me results daywise.

Comment: Is your question how to get the PhysicalNamingStrategy to work at all or only in combination with the extract?

there is an extract and a month function in HQL (see HQL has a `month()` function that is the short version) so you could just use it in a method in your JpaRepository. 

if you can't get your naming strategy to work at all (so not even a simple findById) please post your NamingStrategy implementation

Comment: JpaRepository is working fine, my issue is with the extract how to query on Date type of attribute for month, date or year.

Answer (score -1):

As your JpaRepository works you could just add a function in your Repository

```
@Query("select new my.package.MyDto("
        + "entity.status, "
        + "month(entity.date), "
        + "count(entity.status)) from MyEntity entity"
        + "where month(entity) = 12 "
        + "group by entity.status, month(entity.date) ")
List<MyDto> findGroupedByStatusInDecember();
```

have you tried something similar?